# Possible bug in the Buefy navbar component

Tags: vue.js, buefy

Buefy navbar component is ignoring `mobile-burger` prop value.

According to the documentation https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar/ navbar burger should not be displayed  on mobiles if this prop is false. But looks like it is not like this actually.

```
<b-navbar mobile-burger="false">
            <template slot="brand">
                <b-navbar-item href="/">
                    <div class="logo-text" data-text="logo">logo</div>
                </b-navbar-item>
            </template>
</b-navbar>
```

I expected that if I set mobile-burger="false" then burger will not be displaying on mobiles. But I see no changes.

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Vue attributes are computed only if you use the v-bind syntax.

Because you are not using v-bind, Buefy is passed a String with the value 'false' not a Boolean with a value 'false'.

The result is that 'mobile-burger' evaluates to Boolean 'true' because of the truthiness of there being content other than null, empty string, Boolean false, or a few others values that JavaScript considers 'false'.

```
mobile-burger="false" === String false == Boolean true

v-bind:mobile-burger="false" === Boolean false

:mobile-burger="false" === Boolean false
```

About Truthy values in JavaScript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

### Suggestion

Corrected code might look like this:

```
<b-navbar :mobile-burger="false">
...
</b-navbar>
```

About Vue Template syntax:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html